# Tomcat clustering newbie

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, cluster-computing, high-availability

I am looking into high availability for tomcat.
I read that you can do cluster in Tomcat and as load balancer you can use Apache http.
I can not understand the following:
Is Apache http that is supposed to be the module for load balancing supposed to be installed on a separate machine than Tomcat server?
E.g. If I have 3 tomcat servers to be a cluster, is http supposed to be installed in all 3? Or in an other server?
Also what is the difference if I used Linux facilities for high availability?

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. It looks like a deployment or configuration question better suited to other sites (perhaps http://serverfault.com?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have HA, the users need to always have a response from the DNS name / IP Address they make a request to.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, and some are not even mutually exclusive.

The first tool in the box, so to say, is DNS round robin.

This is where your DNS entry does not have a single IP address, but a list of IP addresses. Each query of your DNS record will return the list in a different order. Client browsers that are DNS round robin aware will try the first entry and fall back to the others in order. Client browsers that are not DNS round robin aware will only try the first entry. That acts as a sort of load balancer... and for the DNS round robin aware client applications, you get a form of automatic fail-over.

The next tool in the box is a load balancer, such as Apache HTTPD or Nginix. These act as the front end that the client sees. They are state aware (hopefully you configure them to be), so they know which of your Tomcat servers are up and which are down, and they route the client requests to servers that have capacity and are up.

So if you want HA. You start by clustering your Tomcat servers... That will most likely require a session store for the cluster... so you use a DB to hold the session store... then you cluster that DB in case of failover... then your but a load balancer in front of the Tomcat instances... then you add a second load balancer in case of a failure in the load balancer... then you use DNS round robin to balance between the load balancers...

You might use ARP broadcast IP address take-over to quickly replace the load balancers in place of, or in addition to DNS round robin...

Then you start to think about geo-redundancy... so you go to the pharmacy and buy a bottle of aspirin!

Before I forget, there is nothing that says you can't do this all on the same hardware... just you run the risk of processes stealing CPU/memory/disk and also the risk of a hardware failure.

The most basic resilient HA that you can get is two machines, both running the DB cluster, both running the Tomcat cluster, both running the Load Balancer, and both configured as DNS round-robin entries for the DNS name of the application

Comment: 1)So I could have 3 tomcats and 3 http on the same machines and be able to do load balancing between these 3 http servers? 2)What about linux modules?

Comment: If you want to do development testing of HA, yes they can be on the same machine. But you cannot call it HA for most peoples definition of HA unless there is a second machine.

Comment: I don't see any major module requirements. The biggest issue I see is getting the DB clustered... as without session clustering you will have to use sticky sessions, and (while great for performance) that will mean that (without session clustering) any users on the failed over node will not see HA. Note: you will typically use stick sessions anyway *with* session clustering

Comment: Oh another form of session clustering you can use (more performant) is in memory, rather than on disk via DB, such as memcached

Comment: `But you cannot call it HA for most peoples definition of HA unless there is a second machine`.But there will be 2-3 tomcat servers.It is just that `http` load b. will be in the same machine as these.Won't the http instances (which will be 3) communicate with each other?

Comment: I also read that DNS round robin is a bad hack.Isn't it?Is there a better way?

Comment: DNS round robin is the "last resort" hack. You don't build HA on DNS round robin. You use DNS round robin to fill the final gap... to fill in for when the DNS TTL hasn't kicked in and the client is still making requests of the dead HTTPD server... at least with DNS RR some of your users will get through (all the ones with DNS RR aware clients and at least 50% of those without (depending on how many DNS RR entries you have))

Comment: Most people use the term HA to refer to the fact that if you pull the power cord on one machine, the application is still running. I remember the first time I tested HA on a production system (which you will need to do) pulling the power cords (redundant PSUs) from one of the servers in the cluster and watching as nothing happened (other than a load spike on the remaining server). If they are all on the same machine... it's not *most people's* definition of HA, so maybe don't call it HA!

Comment: Perhaps I am not clear on this. If I have 2 machines, and there will be a tomcat installed on each machine to form a cluster and also a httpd on each machine for load balancing i.e. 2 tomcats/2 httpd/2 machines, if I pull the cord in one machine I will not have HA you mean?Why?I have 2 machines in this solution

Comment: If you have two machines, and only two machines, and they are on the same LAN, and they are running linux. Get three IP addresses. One for A, one for B and the third is the one that your DNS will point to. Using ARP broadcasting the two nodes can fight over who owns the third IP address (Google "Linux HA"...  you feel lucky) Run HTTPD on both machines and Tomcat on both machines. At any one point in time only one HTTPD will be answering to the IP address that DNS points to, it will route requests to either Tomcat. Pull the plug, the other HTTPD will take over thanks to ARP broadcast

Comment: So you are saying it will work but the idea is that even I have 2 `httpd` only one will do load balancing until one of the crashes and the other takes over?
But still it seems to me you seem to depend on DNS RR which you also mention as a last resort.If it would be possible could you please provide more details since these are new to me and I don't have your background.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20103/discussion-between-stephen-connolly-and-jim)

Answer (score 3):

In general there is no such a restriction that Apache should be implemented on separate machine. In practice you'll probably want to do that.

Apache can be used as a load balancer, so that all the requests will come to apache and it will dispatch the query to some tomcat according to policy (algorithm that will decide when to dispatch to what tomcat, for example round robin).

One apache should be installed and it can communicate with 3 tomcats (any number of tomcats).

BTW, its not necessary should be a software based load balancer like Apache, instead you can use a hardware load balancer.

---

Apache = httpd its a web server that can accept http requests and (among other things) dispatch them to tomcat.

Tomcat is also a web server written in java and its intended for running Java web applications.

So the overall schema should be as follows:

```
client --> Apache (host a) ________  tomcat1 (host b)
                          |________  tomcat2 (host c)
                          |________  tomcat3 (host d)
```

As for hardware load balancers - these a boxes of various manufacturers, like Sisco, F5, and so on.

Hope this helps

Comment: 1)So I could have 3 tomcats and 3 http on the **same machines** and be able to do load balancing between these 3 http servers?
2)What kind of hardware are you refering?3)What about linux modules?

Comment: `One apache should be installed and it can communicate with 3 tomcats`.Yes but where?

Comment: I've updated my answer. As for linux modules, I'm not sure what are you talking about here, all this architecture is not related to any specific operating system. In my schema host a/b/c/d can make use of any operating system. So please elaborate...

Comment: In your diagram, what if it was `Apache (host a)` was installed with `Tomcat (host a)` and `Apache (host b)` was installed with `Tomcat (host b)` and `Apache (host c)` was installed with `Tomcat (host c)`. Is this a possible configuration to avoid an extra machine? Could the 3 `httpd` communicate with each other to form a single cluster?As far as linux I am refering to linux HA extensions (pace maker etc)

Comment: I see... you can install three apaches but it doesn't make any sense. In terms of request processing, tomcat makes all the job. The only purpose to put apache is to provide an entry point to the cluster. After all user should have one entry point. Of course you can create a dns name that will point to more than one server (virtual dns). In this case it does make sense :) It has nothing to do with linux ha extensions though, its different clusters...

Comment: But I am saying 3 http for example and not 1 so as not to have a single point of failure